# problem in using websocket with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, websocket

i'm new to typescript and i wanna create a websocket client using typescript and websocket library. you can see my code below. the problem is when i'm passing an arrow function in this `this.client.on("connect", this.handleConnection);` line of code the code works fine without errors, but when i pass this`this.handleConnection` method i get the below error . what can i do about this?

```
import { Logger } from "./logger";


enum WebsocketStatus{
    CONNECTING = 'connecting',
    STOPPED = 'stopped',
    CONNECTED= 'connected',
    IDLE = 'idle'
}
interface WebsocketInterface{
    getStatus(): WebsocketStatus
    connect(): void
    disconnect(): void
    sendMessage(message: string): void
}

export class WebsocketClient implements WebsocketInterface{
    private status: WebsocketStatus;
    private url: string;
    private logger?: Logger;
    private client: webSocket.client;
    private connection?: webSocket.connection;
    constructor(url: string, logger?: Logger){
        if(logger)
            this.logger = logger;
        this.url = url;
        this.status = WebsocketStatus.IDLE;
        this.client = new webSocket.client();
        this.client.on("connectFailed", this.handleConnectionFailed);
        this.client.on("connect", this.handleConnection);
    }
    getStatus(): WebsocketStatus {
        return this.status;
    }
    connect(): void {
        this.client.connect(this.url);
    }
    disconnect(): void {
        this.connection?.close()
    }
    private handleConnectionFailed(error: Error){
        this.logger?.logError(error.message);
    }
    private handleConnection(connection: webSocket.connection){
        this.connection = connection;
        this.logger?.logInfo(`successfully connected to address ${this.url}`);
        this.connection.on("error", this.handleConnectionError);
        this.connection.on("close", this.handleConnectionClose);
        this.connection.on("message", this.handleConnectionMessage);
    }
    private handleConnectionError(error:Error){
        this.logger?.logError(error.toString());
        this.status = WebsocketStatus.STOPPED;
        this.connection?.close();
    }
    private handleConnectionClose(){
        this.logger?.logInfo("connection closed");
        this.status = WebsocketStatus.STOPPED;
        this.connection?.close();
    }
    private handleConnectionMessage(message: webSocket.Message){
        this.logger?.logInfo(message.toString());

    }
    sendMessage(message: string): void {
        this.connection?.send(message);
    }
}
```

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
> at checkListener (node:events:265:3)
> at _addListener (node:events:545:3)
> at WebSocketConnection.addListener (node:events:604:10)
> at WebSocketClient.handleConnection (/home/mohammad/projects/alphaTrader/digestion/wsConnector.ts:57:25)
> at WebSocketClient.emit (node:events:512:28)
> at WebSocketClient.emit (node:domain:489:12)
> at WebSocketClient.succeedHandshake (/home/mohammad/projects/alphaTrader/digestion/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:348:10)
> at WebSocketClient.validateHandshake (/home/mohammad/projects/alphaTrader/digestion/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:332:10)
> at ClientRequest.handleRequestUpgrade (/home/mohammad/projects/alphaTrader/digestion/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketClient.js:261:14)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:512:28) {
> code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
> }

Comment: How are you instantiating `WebsocketClient`?

Comment: In the constructor, try passing `this.handleConnection.bind(this)`

Comment: @Carcigenicate  like this 
```import { Logger } from "./logger";
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import { WebsocketClient } from "./wsConnector";
dotenv.config();
const logger = Logger.getInstance();
const websocket = new WebsocketClient(process.env.COINEX_WEBSOCKET_URL || 'wss://socket.coinex.com/', logger);
websocket.connect();```

Comment: @cbr after adding these codes to constructor i still have the problem . 

``` this.handleConnection.bind(this);
        this.handleConnectionFailed.bind(this);
        this.handleConnectionMessage.bind(this);
        this.handleConnectionError.bind(this);
        this.handleConnectionClose.bind(this);
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant like: `this.client.on("connect", this.handleConnection.bind(this));
`

Comment: @cbr it worked! thanks a lot.